# «Esta questão não é de todo clara!»

Tags: significado, etimologia, estrangeirismos

Antes de lerem o resto da pergunta, gostaria que parassem uns segundos para pensar no significado do título. Significa que a questão não é completamente clara: compreende-se alguma coisa, mas há alguns pontos que levantam dúvidas? Significa que a questão é completamente incompreensível? Outro exemplo:

> (a) A janela não está ***de todo*** aberta.

Significa isto que a janela está parcialmente aberta? Que está fechada?

Esta dúvida ocorreu-me, ou melhor, 'recorreu-me', ao ouvir na segunda passada a Ana Galvão nas [*Donas da Casa*, RTP Antena 3](http://www.rtp.pt/play/p2025/e218918/as-donas-da-casa) (ao minuto 79) dizer qualquer coisa como (ênfase minha):

> (b) São 11h21. Ai, tinha prometido que não dava as horas. E porquê? Porque há muita gente de férias, que está relaxada, e que não quer saber as horas, ***de todo***, muito menos quando é de manhã.

Ora, eu acho que comecei a ouvir, e só esporadicamente, este uso do *de todo*, no fim duma frase para reforçar o *não* anterior, há coisa de uns quinze anos. E sempre o achei estranho, e um decalque do inglês *(not) at all*. (Também poderia ser do francês *(pas) du tout*, mas quem é que ainda decalca coisas do francês?)

Ora o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-expressao-de-todo/30018) não estranha a expressão, diz que significa *completamente, totalmente*, e apresenta os seguintes exemplos de Énio Ramalho, *Dicionário Estrutural, Estilístico e Sintáctico da Língua Portuguesa* (1985) (ênfase minha):

> (c) «Aquele rapaz anda tolo ***de todo*** [...].»
>
> (d) «Não se podem considerar ainda ***de todo*** esclarecidas as razões que o levaram a demitir-se do cargo.»
>
> (e) «O traço da dureza faltava ***de todo*** no estilo daquele escritor.»

Os exemplos acima com o *de todo* substituído por *completamente* soam lindamente, mas *não querem saber as horas, completamente*?! Portanto o *de todo* da Ana Galvão (e do consulente do Ciberdúvidas) é o mesmo *de todo* dos exemplos do Énio Ramalho? [Este outro artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/-de-todo/14239) apresenta este exemplo:

> (f) «Os filmes de ficção científica não são, ***de todo***, os meus favoritos.»

No artigo afirma-se que *de todo* significa completamente e que reforça a negação da frase. Mas em (d), parece-me que atenua a negação (não estão completamente esclarecidas as razões). A diferença parece ser conseguida pelo isolamento ou não do *de todo* do resto da frase por vírgulas.

**Depois de tudo isto, as questões que eu gostaria de ver esclarecidas são as seguintes:**

1. Qual é significado de (a): a janela está fechada ou parcialmente aberta? E do mesmo modo, qual o significado do meu título e de (d)?
2. Faz de facto diferença o isolamento do *de todo* por vírgulas? Isto é, *de todo* reforça a negação em (b) e (f) e atenua-a no meu título, em (a) e (d)?
3. Este uso do *de todo*, que reforça a negação, é de facto uma inovação recente, ou já está presente na língua há muito e eu é que não dei por ele?
4. Se é inovação, quando e onde é que aconteceu? Não encontrei exemplos deste uso em sites brasileiros. Será um fenómeno exclusivamente de Portugal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De facto, existem, pelo menos, dois *de todo*s.

Um deles significa *completamente*, e pode ser usada tanto em contextos positivos como negativos (exemplos do CETEMPúblico):

> *par=ext1953-soc-97a-2*: A esta questão, aquele responsável respondeu de forma menos peremptória, repetindo que «houve contaminação, o que é **de todo** inaceitável, pois pressupõe riscos e também quebra das normas relativas às características das águas minerais».
>
> *par=ext871570-eco-96b-2*: A esta abertura manifestada pelo Governo não estará **de todo** alheia a própria natureza do processo, já que o estudo nasce de um repto lançado por Guterres a Belmiro de Azevedo para que fossem os privados a encontrar soluções para o desastre iminente do sector florestal nacional.

Segundo a [resposta do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-expressao-de-todo/30018) que citaste, este *de todo* parece ter algumas limitações que *completamente* não tem, pelo menos a julgar pela inaceitabilidade de «estão de todo esclarecidas as razões» (são mencionadas conotações depreciativas, disfóricas ou de ausência). Julgando pelos exemplos do CETEMPúblico, quando não há negação *de todo* aparece geralmente associado a *estranho*, *impossível*, *inconveniente*, *inviável*, *desconhecido*, *impensável*, etc., mas também a expressões que parecem fugir a esta regra:

> *par=ext223309-clt-92a-2*: As duas da manhã é a hora mais usada pelos frequentadores habituais do States para entrar e, neste caso, é **de todo** aconselhável que se reja pelos seus costumes.

O outro *de todo* é aquele mais semelhante ao inglês *at all*, e parece ser uma expressão de polaridade negativa. O significado é semelhande a locuções adverbiais de negação como *de forma alguma/nenhuma* (ou *de jeito nenhum*, como se diz comummente no Brasil), mas parece não ser completamente equivalente. Nas três respostas abaixo, seria perfeitamente aceitável usar *de forma alguma*:

> P: Gostaste do espetáculo?
>   R: Não, não gostei **de todo**.
>   ? R: Não, **de todo**.
>   ?? R: **De todo**.

Aparece geralmente entre vírgulas porque não se associa a adjetivos e particípios como o outro *de todo*, funcionando mais como um apêndice enfático. Vejamos as diferenças:

> (1) Ele não é estúpido de todo. / Ele não é de todo estúpido. [= não é completamente estúpido]
>   (2) Ele não é estúpido, de todo. / Ele não é, de todo, estúpido [= decidadamente, não é estúpido]

Um exemplo do CETEMPúblico:

> *par=ext22790-clt-94b-2*: Sagebrecht não é, **de todo**, tão gorda como parece, apenas um pouco rechonchuda.

Agora, de facto sucede que a vírgula nem sempre é colocada, o que pode gerar frases ambíguas (a negação cobre ou não a expressão *de todo*?). Por exemplo, a frase seguinte é um litote que significa que é até bastante provável ou significa que existe apenas uma pequena possibilidade?

> *par=ext182553-eco-96a-2:* Mas não é **de todo** impossível, se a retoma económica se restabelecer no segundo semestre de 1996.

Nestas frases tende a não ocorrer vírgula porque *de todo* não está a separar um verbo e um complemento. Nelas interpreto *de todo* como *de forma alguma*, mas também é discutível:

> *par=ext20980-soc-96a-1*: Uma situação que, do ponto de vista da PGR, não se justificava **de todo**, atendendo a que o Maria Pia, até 1988, fazia em média apenas 300 colheitas e transfusões por ano, [...]
>
> *par=ext169839-opi-96b-3*: E é isso que não se compreende **de todo**, sobretudo diante das proporções que o caso foi assumindo.

Neste caso não há vírgulas, mas pelo contexto, só pode significar *de forma alguma*/*decidadamente*:

> *par=ext7919-nd-91b-1:* O meu drama, neste momento, é que, quando eu não estou a trabalhar, não estou **de todo** a trabalhar.

Neste caso há vírgula, mas o significado é *completamente* (de resto, não há contexto negativo):

> *par=ext117837-clt-soc-95b-1*: Embora possa ter lido em qualquer lugar que o Linux pode ser instalado em apenas 60 minutos, isto é, **de todo**, falso.

Repare-se que há passagens do início dos anos 90, por isso este significado não terá surgido «nos últimos 15 anos».

Comment: Não conseguiste então encontrar exemplos do segundo *de todo* anteriores aos anos 90? Gostava de apurar isso. Não se pode isolar o *de todo* com vírgulas quando este não separa verbo de complemento (penúltimo, antepenúltimo e ante-antepenúltimo exemplo)? Mesmo entendendo o *de todo* como apêndice enfático? Creio que com vírgulas as frases ficariam com a mesma estrutura que a minha transcrição da Ana Galvão.

Comment: A questão é que a maioria do material do CETEMPúblico é dessa altura. A razão por que o escolhi é que domino a sintaxe (pesquisar só por "de todo" dá muitos falsos positivos: "de todos os/estes/..."). Posso tentar outra vez ver é possível excluir determinantes no CRPC, onde de resto encontrei um exemplo interessante "como a sua ausência nos domínios dos transportes [...] de todo não permite questionar." -- o escopo da negação não inclui "de todo", tal como no 2o "de todo", mas não é parafraseável por "de forma alguma" (tem lá um "não"). Não sei se se diria hoje algo assim.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu revi a minha resposta. Admito que se possa usar a vírgula, mas ela deixa de ser tão necessária como quando estamos a separar uma cópula do predicativo do sujeito. A vírgula pode ainda assim ajudar a perceber que o _de todo_ não é incluído na negação.

Comment: @Jacinto Consegui encontrar [esta passagem](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/context.php?batch=934&qname=ezj9b8pi6iO&uT=y) datada de 1963, se bem que não tenho muita confiança de que o ano esteja correto. Mas parece ser muito raro entre os textos literários do CRPC (os únicos que geralmente estão datados).

Comment: E esta outra de 1989: http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/context.php?batch=799&qname=ezj9b8pi6iO&uT=y O mesmo livro tem outras passagens do género "ou se faz em dada altura ou não se faz de todo". Parece certo que no final dos anos 80 já estava bem difundido.

Comment: Neste últimos não há dúvida. Na de 1963 o significado não de todo claro.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo às suas perguntas:

1. Em (a) A janela não está **de todo** aberta significa que ela não está **totalmente** aberta.  Da mesma forma, a pergunta título afirma que "a pergunta não está **totalmente** clara" i.e., ela deixa dúvidas. Em (d) Não se podem considerar ainda **de todo** esclarecidas as razões", significa, também, "**....totalmente** esclarecidas"
2. Sim, o isolamento por vírgulas parece acentuar a negação.
3. O uso de "de todo" em (b) e (f) não me parece idiomático. **Soa como uma tradução mal feita** do Inglês.
4. O uso de **"de todo" em (a) e (d)** não é algo recente. Já ouço em ptBR há longa data.  Já o uso em **(b) e (f)** soa estranho aos meus ouvidos.

Comment: Pois, eu partilho dos teus sentimentos. Mas gostaria de encontrar evidência mais contreta de que o *de todo* de (b) e (f) é mesmo uma modernice. A minha pergunta 4 refere-se só a este útlimo *de todo*, a possível inovação. *De todo* como *completamente* já vem do tempo dos afonsinhos.

Comment: @Jacinto O Priberam por outro lado só regista [_de todo em todo_](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/de%20todo) significando _completamente_. _De todo_ diz apenas ser _de maneira nenhuma_ (o significado alegadamente moderno).

Comment: @Artefacto Mas a [Infopédia regista *de todo*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/todo) como sinónimo de *de todo em todo*, significando *absolutamente*

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, parece-me pura e simplemente uma falha do Priberam. O significado _completamente_ é até provavelmente mais comum e está na base de expressões algo idiomáticas como "não é mau de todo".

Comment: @Artefacto E olha como o [Priberam explica o advérbio *meio*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/meio): mais ou menos, não de todo, quase